# Angular app in subfolder with unpredictable name

Tags: angular, path, deep-linking

I have an Angular 7 that is automatically deployed to several locations and I cannot set a static value for base href, since I do not know folder names in advance.

Generated index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>App name</title>
    <base href="./">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.[hash].css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.[hash].js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.[hash].js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.[hash].js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This app is automatically deployed to different uri, something like those:

- https://host1/
- https://host2/
- https://host1/path1/
- https://host2/path2/

Host names and path names are not predictable by me.

All of this works fine since I start navigation from app root and navigate by links, but one of the requirement is the use of deep linking, I set up all routes and they work well also, but everything broke when I start navigation from a deep route (i.e. refresh browser page), for example:

- https://host1/route1/
- https://host2/route2/variable/
- https://host1/path1/route1/route3/routeN/

The routes works well if I load application starting from root, but in sub routes my browser is unable to locate all files.

This is because the browser is asking for files that

**Additional informations**

- The webserver is Apache, I do not have control nor visibility on that;
- In every scenario index.html is correctly served, there is probably the correct rewrite rule at least for first file;
- I tried to set APP_BASE_HREF using a snippet from another answer, but this approach is not applicable since every JavaScript file is not loaded in my application;
- I think that I could solve my issue modifying .htaccess file in every installation, but I'm waiting for system login but it may be unavailable.

How can I make this work?